# How to generate a random sequence matrix

Tags: r, matrix, random, sequence

i need to generate 2 random matrixes of 5x1 and 1x5, with sequential numbers from 1:100. replace must be true.

i also do not want to use packages.

for example

[1,2,3,4,5]
or
[3,4,5,6,7]
or
[13,14,15,16,17]

(1x5 matrixes not in the example ;))

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x <- sample(1:96,1)

# for 5x1 matrix
matrix(x:(x+4) , 5)

# for 1x5 matrix
matrix(x:(x+4) , 1)
```